# Route::resources и префикс имени маршрута

Tags: laravel, маршрутизация

Имеем такие роуты.

```
Route::group(['namespace'=>'Admin', 'prefix'=>'admin', 'middleware' => 'admin'], function () {
Route::get('/', 'DashboardController@dashboard')->name('dashboard');
Route::resources([
    'users' => 'UsersController',
    'categories' => 'CategoryController'
]);
});
```

Необходимо, чтобы имена этих ресурсов начинались с префикса 'admin'. Для `Route::resource()` это делается просто:

```
Route::resource('categories', 'CategoryController'', ['as' => 'admin']);
```

Вопрос: как это сделать для `Route::resources()`?  Можно ссылку на документацию, ибо по данной теме я ничего не нашел.

Answer (score 0):

Вот как решается.

```
Route::group(['as' => 'admin.'], function() {
    Route::resources([
        'users' => 'UsersController',
        'categories' => 'CategoryController'
    ]);
});
```